# Vertically center <table> in <div> dynamically based on row count?

Tags: html, css, html-table, vertical-alignment

I've created a JS Fiddle to demonstrate my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/pqTqH/

How can I update my CSS so that the table is vertically centered **without** setting the `height` of the table or a `top-margin`? I want the table to remain centered even when there is only 1 row. Ultimately, I just need this to be dynamic so I can add rows to my table via Jquery and the table will remain centered (vertically and horizontally) in the `<div>`.

**NOTE:** There will always be at least one row, but no more than 15, so the table should always fit inside the `<div>`.

Comment: with the use of javascript?

Comment: I changed your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pqTqH/1/) to not have the blue background.

Comment: @SvenBieder Yep, Javascript is fine

Comment: @MiniRagnarok Thanks, looks better!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a simple fix using `table-cell`, which you hinted at in your fiddle:

```
#right {
    height: 450px;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: #CCCCFF;
    font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 14px;
    color: #333;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

In your original example, you declared `float: left` and as a result `div#right` will not behave like a `table-cell` since its `display` value is computed to be `block`, so you lose the vertical alignment control.

Reference: To learn more about computer value of `display`, see:
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo

Comment: Glad to help! I added a reference concerning computed display values.

Comment: @BradM I appreciate that and the alternative would be to explicitly mark-up the table as you showed earlier.  It depends on how critical the centering is to the client.  In the worse case, I lose the vertical alignment in the older IE browsers.  I might be okay with that, others, maybe not.  However, it is good to have both solutions posted with a discussion of pros and cons.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Put your table *inside* another table, like in the following code sample:

```
<div id="right">
    <table style="vertical-align: middle; height: 100%; width: 100%;">
        <tr>
            <td>
               // your table
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually do this through an onload/window.resize event in jQuery because I do not have to change how my DOM is layed out or fight with CSS.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pqTqH/4/)

```
$(function() {
    centerTable();
    $(window).resize(centerTable);
});

function centerTable()
{
    var right = $('#right');
    var table = $('#right table');
    $('#right table').css('margin-top', ((right.height() - table.height()) / 2) + 'px');
}
```

I've updated your jsFiddle example with a jquery onload event. If you do not care about window resize you can run the code once in your onload event. This could also be shortened to a 1 liner by not using the 2 vars.